# Using jimport in my own script

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

When i try to use jimport('joomla.user.helper') it gives me this error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function jimport() in /home/joomclan/public_html/quiz/pop_fetching.php on line 223

This is my code where i use this:

```
 function addJoomlaUser($name, $username, $password, $email) {
  jimport('joomla.user.helper');
  $salt   = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(32);
  $crypted  = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($password, $salt);
  $cpassword = $crypted.':'.$salt;

  $data = array(
      "name"=>$name,
      "username"=>$username,
      "password"=>$password,
      "password2"=>$password,
      "email"=>$email,
      "block"=>0,
      "groups"=>array("1","2")
  );
```

Comment: make sure the joomla extension is properly added in your script before this code appears. Where is jimport() defined?

Comment: Are you creating a new Joomla! extension or creating an external application that needs to access Joomla's data etc...

Comment: An external script in which i need to add Joomla users ..

Answer (score 0):

add at the top

`include(JPATH_BASE.'libraries/loader.php')`

but, afraid, something wrong with your code

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?226904-jimport-in-Joomla-how-does-it-work

> It's defined in "libraries/loader.php", which is included by "libraries/joomla/import.php", which is included by "includes/framework.php", which is included by "index.php" (all paths relative to the base Joomla directory).

Probably this will be helpful as well
[jimport not working in Joomla 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871800/jimport-not-working-in-joomla-1-5)

Answer (score 0):

in your script, at the top, initialise joomla framework as below.

```
`define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$app =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$app->initialise();
jimport( 'joomla.user.user' );`
```

I always use that.